# A surrogate function for validation error in order to perform hyper-parameter optimization?

Tags: hyperparameter, bayesian-optimization, out-of-sample, tuning

Greed search CV or few other approaches may be computationally expensive in hyper-parameter tuning. Is it possible to come up with a surrogate model or a purposed model for a validation error in order to automate hyper-parameter tuning?